# Turn string of a multi dimensional array into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to convert a string like

`"[[[1 2 3]\n [2 3 4]]]"`

into a numpy array

`[[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]]`

How do I do this using Python?

Answer (score 1):

You could transform your string into a representation that python can evaluate as list (or list of lists) and then convert it into a numpy array, e.g:

```
import ast

raw =  "[[[1 2 3]\n [2 3 4]]]"
arr_str = raw.replace(" ", ",").replace("\n","")
arr = np.array(ast.literal_eval(arr_str))
```

Comment: There's a space after \n so it becomes ",," after every array.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, however I have no idea if there is a more efficient way (perhaps the better minds of SO can enlighten us). This would provide the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import json
import re

string = "[[[1 2 3]\n [2 3 4]]]"
string = json.loads(re.sub("\s+", ",", string.strip()))
string = np.array(string)

print(type(string))
```

With an output of:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: I got array([1, 2, 3])

Comment: I'm not sure why - running that exact script using your input string gives an output array of [[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]]. Maybe double check your input?

Comment: yup my bad. is this faster than using ast?

Comment: You would have to run a test to determine the speed. Looking at both answers, I would make use of P. Leibner's replacement method (due to it being more concise and not requiring an import), but I would still use ```json.loads()``` in place of ```ast.literal_eval()```. That is due to preference.